# Why nodemon not working or anything else regarding that

Tags: node.js, nodemon

My JS file path is:

> $ nodemon /var/www/html/team/hemant/Module/NodeExample/app.js

When I run this command it shows:

> nodemon : command not found.

Comment: did u install it globally ? `npm install -g nodemon` ?

Comment: i install it in my working directory...

Comment: like my working dirctory is var/www/html/team/hemant/Module/ and the  node_module folder is created in that  i install nodemon module

Comment: from the documentation: `Note that as of npm v1, you must explicitly tell npm to install globally as nodemon is a command line utility.`

Comment: i install nodemon globally: npm install -g nodemon......but its not working.....